# Windows 2008 DNS Forward rules

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, internal-dns

I have Windows 2008 DNS service
Internal DNS service have A-records, for example:
test.mycompany.com -> 1.1.1.1

on external side: 
Domain have external A-records 
test.mycompany.com -> 1.1.1.1
newtest.mycompany.com  -> 2.2.2.2

test.mycompany.com  work in both cases
But when i try to resolve newtest.mycompany.com via Windows Internal DNS service i got:

> newtest.mycompany.com: Non-existent domain

What I must change for use subdomain forwarding?

So, If my internal DNS  server haven`t A record -> It return A record from (internet) domain servers.

Comment: If I don't have 'A' record in internal DNS I want External NS server to resolve address, not to resolve via Windows DNS server.

Comment: Are you saying that you want a public DNS server to host your internal domain?

Comment: You can't put a bounty out on a question and not answer the questions people need to help you.  Help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

With split DNS (internal and external DNS providers both serving the same domain) there's no automatic way to have your internal DNS answer for what it knows and forward the rest.  You can either keep them in sync manually by creating all the public records in your internal DNS as well as external, or by delegating them (one name at a time) from your internal DNS to the external DNS.

So in this case, create an A record for newtest in the zone for company.com at 2.2.2.2 or create a delegation record for newtest in the zone for company.com pointing to the nameserver for the externally hosted DNS.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options
add test.mycompany.com NS Records for the public name servers. or 
add test.mycompany.com as a Stub zone.

You also need to duplicate the A records for your NS servers locally if they are in the same zone.

[Stub Zones](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754190.aspx)

[Zone Delegation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771640.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an A record for newtest.mycompany.com to your internal DNS server. Your internal DNS server is authoritative for the mycompany.com DNS zone (from it's perspective). It's not going to forward requests for records it doesn't have or can't find in the mycompany.com DNS zone to your external DNS server.

Comment: What I need for use external dns if internal have no records?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: - Rephrase original Question

Answer (score 0):

Get a CNAME record for newtest.mycompany.com as "newtest.mycompany2.com" on your internal DNS. Get a DNS hosting for mycompany2.com, add an A record for newtest.mycompany2.com to what ever IP address you want returned.